# Percentages in CPU profiler in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, cpu, profiler

What do the percentages in the chrome cpu profiler for the "Heavy (Bottom Up)" view indicate?  Specifically I mean in the "Total" column.
I had thought percentage of total cpu time (as in total cpu time over the course of the profile recording) but if this is the case then the numbers don't make sense to me since the total amount of cpu percentage time added up is greater than 100 in some cases for me.  Does it mean rather the percentage of total cpu time in the function call alone?  If so how does that make sense?  Or does it possibly indicate only cpu time on a single core and thus having multiple cores will return percentages with a sum greater than 100?

Thanks!

Comment: In which page are you recording?

Comment: In the "Profiles" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusive times don't add up to 100%, they exceed it, so don't add them up. Suppose you have routine A that calls B, and B that calls C, and so on through D, E, F, and finally to G that actually cranks the CPU for 100% of the time. Then F has 100% inclusive time, and so does E, D, on up to A.

Inclusive time is far more useful to know than self time, 1) because it includes self time, and 2) because the problem could very well be in any one of those routines, not just G.

Therefore it gives you more places to look for speedups, with the result that you find more.

Comment: So by inclusive time, are you referring to the Total Time column?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that A calls B, B Calls C, and C was executing half of the profiling time. If A and B did nothing but call B and C correspondingly then total time will be 50% for each of A, B and C. It sums up to 150% as you noticed. Self time however is 0% for A and B and 50% for C.

On the second level in the Bottom Up view total time is the total time of the *root* function when it was on top of the callstack ending at the node on the second level. The same applies recursively to all deeper levels.

This is more complicated for recursive call. See also http://crbug.com/523537 for recent changes in that area.

Comment: Actually, recursion is not an issue. Inclusive time fraction is simply the fraction of time the function is on the stack, because if it could be made to take no time, that is the fraction by which total time would be reduced. Check the 2nd answer, 4th point, on [*this post*](https://archive.is/9r927). This still confuses people, and it need not.

Comment: All of that describes behavior of top-down view and the top level in the bottom-up view. Recursion case is only more complicated when you expand callers in the bottom-up view (levels 2 and deeper).

Comment: Suppose you're working from stack samples, taken every 10ms for, say 10s, for 1000 samples. Suppose recursive function F appears on 400 of them. Since it is recursive, it can appear multiple times within a single sample, but it still is only present on 400 samples. That means its inclusive time is 40%. Why? Because if it were accelerated so it took 0 time (or deleted, or not called), no sample could hit it, because it has no exposure to the clock. So those 400 samples containing it will not occur, leaving only 600. So that 40%, or 4 seconds, is saved. Forget levels, top-down or bottom-up.

Comment: Does it contradict to anything of what I wrote above?

Comment: Assume A calls B, one sample contains stack A->B and another 9 contain just A. In top-down view A total time is 10, B total time is 1. In _bottom-up view_ B total time is 1 and if you expand its callers you'll see A whose total time is 1 not 10. This is oftentimes confusing and I believe the question was about it.

Comment: What's confusing is that you're picking a node and confining your attention to it, so that makes your estimate of total (inclusive) time for other nodes relative to the node you started from, and to your choice of whether to look down or up. Assuming the goal is *performance tuning*, what you need to know is what fraction of *overall* time any node (function or statement) is responsible for. That is just the fraction of time it is on the stack. (You also need to know *why* it is spending that time, and that information is also encoded in the stack samples.)